# how to make a box for cascading multiple questions and answers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I ask for help.
    I would like to create troubleshooting for a guideline with multiple questions and answers to guide the worker to follow the correct processes.
      I created an example, but the yes box doesn't work for me ... how can I do?
the problem is that if I click yes or no it returns the same answer, I have to make sure that by clicking yes I have an answer and clicking no I have another different answer with other boxes

thank you!

```
<style>
 ul, #myUL {
 list-style-type: none;
 }

  #myUL {
  margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   } 

  .box {
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ */
 -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
 -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
 user-select: none;
 }

.box::before {
 content: "\2610";
 color: black;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 6px;
 }

.check-box::before {
 content: "\2611"; 
 color: dodgerblue;
 }

.nested {
 display: none;
 }

 .active {
  display: block;
  }
  </style>

 <ul id="myUL">
 <li>  beverage?</li>
 <li><span class="box">yes</span>
 <li><span class="box">no</span>
 <ul class="nested">
 <li>eat?</li>
 <li><span class="box">yes</span>
 <li><span class="box">no</span>
 <ul class="nested">
 <li>ecc</li>

<script>
var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
 toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {                                      this.parentElement.querySelector(".nested").classList.toggle("active");
this.classList.toggle("check-box");
  });
 }
  </script>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/erfmjd5v/4/

Comment: the problem is that if I click yes or no it returns the same answer, I have to make sure that by clicking yes I have an answer and clicking no I have another different answer with other boxes

Answer (score 0):

Closing `li & ul tag` Properly

```
<ul id="myUL">
    <li>beverage?</li>
    <li><span class="box">yes</span>
        <span class="box">no</span>
        <ul class="nested">
            <li>eat?</li>
            <li><span class="box">yes</span>
                <span class="box">no</span>
                <ul class="nested">
                    <li>ecc</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/erfmjd5v/4/

Comment: the problem is that if I click yes or no it returns the same answer, I have to make sure that by clicking yes I have an answer and clicking no I have another different answer with other boxes

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `<ul>` element is meant to be used this way.
Here's an alternative user interface to consider:

```js
// Declares questions array and results object for reference
let questions = [
  { id: "q1", terminal: false, yes: "q2",       no: "q5"       },
  { id: "q2", terminal: false, yes: "q3",       no: "q4"       },
  { id: "q3", terminal: true,  yes: "result3y", no: "result3n" },
  { id: "q4", terminal: true,  yes: "result4y", no: "result4n" },
  { id: "q5", terminal: false, yes: "q6",       no: "q7"       },
  { id: "q6", terminal: true,  yes: "result6y", no: "result6n" },
  { id: "q7", terminal: true,  yes: "result7y", no: "result7n" }
];

let results = {
  result3y: "blue",
  result3n: "green",
  result4y: "red",
  result4n: "yellow",
  result6y: "black",
  result6n: "white",
  result7y: "brown",
  result7n: "grey"
};

// Runs the processResult function when the user clicks on the page 
document.addEventListener("click", processResponse);

function processResponse(event) { // `event` is the click that triggered the function
  // Makes sure a box was clicked before proceeding
  if(event.target.classList.contains("box")){
    // Identifies HTML elements (and the 'response' data attribute)
    const
      box = event.target,
      question = box.parentElement,
      response = box.dataset.response,
      boxAndSibling = question.querySelectorAll(".box"),
      sibling = response == "no" ? boxAndSibling[0] : boxAndSibling[1],
      resultDisplay = document.getElementById("result");

    // Makes sure the other box is not already checked before proceeding        
    if(!sibling.classList.contains("check-box")){
      box.classList.add("check-box");
      
      // Finds the question in the array
      for(let quest of questions){
        if(quest.id == question.id){
          
         // Shows the result for terminal questions
         if(quest.terminal){
            result = quest[response];
            resultDisplay.innerHTML = `Secret color: ${results[result]}`;
          }
          // Or otherwise shows the next question
          else{
            const next = document.getElementById(quest[response]);
            next.classList.add("active");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
ul { list-style-type: none; }
#myUL { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.box {
  cursor: pointer; -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; 
  -ms-user-select: none;  user-select: none;
}
.box::before { content: "\2610"; color: black; display: inline-block; margin-right: 6px; }

.check-box::before { content: "\2611"; color: dodgerblue; }

.nested { display: none; }
.active { display: block; }

#result{ font-size: 2em; }
```

```html
<div id="q1">
  <span>Animal?</span><br />
  <span class="box" data-response="yes">Yes</span><br />
  <span class="box" data-response="no">No</span><br />
</div>
<div id="q2" class="nested">
  <span>Mammal?</span><br />
  <span class="box" data-response="yes">Yes</span><br />
  <span class="box" data-response="no">No</span><br />
</div>
<div id="q3" class="nested">
  <span>Platypus?</span><br />
  <span class="box" data-response="yes">Yes</span><br />
  <span class="box" data-response="no">No</span><br />
</div>
<div id="q4" class="nested">
  <span>Fish?</span><br />
  <span class="box" data-response="yes">Yes</span><br />
  <span class="box" data-response="no">No</span><br />
</div>
<div id="q5" class="nested">
  <span>Vegetable?</span><br />
  <span class="box" data-response="yes">Yes</span><br />
  <span class="box" data-response="no">No</span><br />
</div>
<div id="q6" class="nested">
  <span>Tuber?</span><br />
  <span class="box" data-response="yes">Yes</span><br />
  <span class="box" data-response="no">No</span><br />
</div>
<div id="q7" class="nested">
  <span>Fungus?</span><br />
  <span class="box" data-response="yes">Yes</span><br />
  <span class="box" data-response="no">No</span><br />
</div>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: we're almost there, I wish the answer could be removed with the same click is it possible?
because in this example once the flag has been inserted in the box it is no longer possible to remove ..
This work is for employees who can verify the procedure based on the customer's questions.
Can the final result be removed?
I need it for customer support workers.

Comment: Sure, you'd just assign an empty string ("") instead of a result, like: `resultDisplay.innerHTML = ""`.

Comment: ok, and to uncheck the box?
in the example I can't remove the flag from the box ...
thank you

Comment: Oh, you can just use `classList.toggle()`, as you did before, instead of `classList.add()`. I changed it because I thought `.toggle()` gave unintuitive behavior (removing `.active` from the next question but not from other dependent questions (e.g. two questions later.)) If this bothers you, I guess you could fix it by  using `classList.remove` to take the class away from all the later questions in the tree.

Comment: OK it's good! and how can I do to enter the answer under each question?
example:
what car do you have?
question 1 renault?
question 2
fiat?
question 3
honda?
the answer right now is at the bottom, I would like it to be under every answer on the list